# How can I generate a random angle in radians in this range?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

What I do to generate a random angle is this:

```
float rand_angle = (float)random_.NextDouble() * MathHelper.TwoPi;
```

But I want to generate a random angle from range [a;b], excluding everything in the middle.

Ho Can I do it?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I want to generate a random angle from range [a;b], excluding everything in the middle.

Assuming `b` is greater than `a`, that's just a matter of getting a value in the range `[0, b - a)` and then adding `a`:

```
float randomAngle = (float) (random.NextDouble() * (b - a) + a);
```